# How to animate an image in TitleBar?

Tags: android, animation, imageview

I'm trying to make a logo animation in a TitleBar.
Everything would work just fine, if an animation didn't reuqire a trigger.

I have a method

```
public void animateLogo() {
    if (imageView != null) {
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.logo_animation);
        logoAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) imageView.getBackground();
        logoAnimation.start();
    }
}
```

When triggered by a button works just fine. But I want it to start independently of any button presses. It should work since starting the App till the end without any interactions.

When calling the method in OnCreate(..) it doesn't work. onStart() the same.

Any ideas how to achieve the result ?

Answer (score 0):

Try starting the animation from `onWindowFocusChanged()` instead of from `onCreate()`.  I guess animations won't start until after the creation process is totally finished.